# Object viewing from far distances

Tags: game-engine, objects

I've created mountains for a scene in the game I'm creating...
The problem is, when I go into camera, you can only see a little bit of the mountains when they're generally quite huge. Anything in general, and it's not mist so I don't know what's the problem and is this fixable.

[image]

Any suggestions...
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try changing the clipping value of the camera.?[image]

Comment: Oops my bad, it's what I was looking for. Thank heaps!